# Doubly Linked List Destructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a program that uses doubly linked lists yet my destructor causes an error. I am not sure why this is occurring so an explanation would be great as well as possible steps for a solution.

```
~GroceryList()
    {
        ItemType *before=head, *current=head, *after=head;
        for(int i=0; i<itemCount; i++)
        {
            before=current;
            current=current->next;
            after=current->next;
            before->next=after;
            after->prev=before;
            delete current;
        }
        current=before=after=NULL;
    };
```

Comment: If this list isn't circular, there is roughly twice as much code as needed for properly cleaning up. a single victim pointer and advancing the `head` member prior to `delete`-ing the victim should suffice. [See eample](http://pastebin.com/rdhjKdEr).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Your example worked well and makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: Using a standard container such as `std::list<>` or `std::vector<>` would make even more sense =P. But I realize this is likely academia driven. Best of luck regardless.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should show error msg.
I think below line is creating problem.

```
for(int i=0; i<itemCount; i++)
        {
    before=current;     //  this one 
    current=current->next;
    after=current->next;
    before->next=after;
    after->prev=before;
    delete current;     // here you are deleting and again using `current` in first statement in loop?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error.

```
for(int i=0; i<itemCount; i++)
{
    before=current;
    current=current->next; 
    after=current->next;
    before->next=after;
    after->prev=before;

    // Add some statements to print the conents of
    // before, current, and after here to debug
    // the memory problem.

    delete current;
    current = after;  // Add this line.
}
```

Comment: @R_Sahu: I attempted to add that line and it did not help with the destructor. My error is "Unhandled exception at 0x011D3ABF in CPSC 131 Project 1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000002C." Which occurs at the line right above the delete current command.

Comment: @gameboy1995, I am not sure what's causing the memory problem. Add some debugging statements at the location I suggest in my answer.